# Retrieve XCode Project from iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

If I have an app I developed installed on my device, can I retrieve the original code?

I seem to have misplaced the XCode project between my different computers and hard drives for an old app I made. However, I still have the app installed on my iPad. I really need some of the code from this app. Can I possibly plug my iPad into my mac and retrieve some of the code from my iPad? (I know some stats are visible in iTunes. Can I view the app info there?)

Comment: No. Your iPad doesn't contain any "code".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A compiled app doesn't contain any of the app's Swift or Objective-C source code.